# Retrieve database values and display in piechart

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I am creating a website using python and Django.

I want to display the data in pie chart. As of now, I created it as static.
But now I want to retrieve my mongodb values and display it in pie chart.

Here's my HTML markup:

```
<body>
<div id = "container" style = "width:100%; height:100%"></div>
<script>
    anychart.onDocumentReady(function() {
        var data = [
        {x: "White", value: 223553265},
        {x: "Black or African American", value: 38929319},
        {x: "American Indian and Alaska Native", value: 2932248},
        {x: "Asian", value: 14674252},
        {x: "Native Hawaiian and Other Pacific Islander", value: 540013},
        {x: "Some Other Race", value: 19107368},
        {x: "Two or More Races", value: 9009073}

        ]
     var chart = anychart.pie();
        chart.title("Current Shift Defect %")
        chart.data(data);
        chart.container('container');
        chart.draw();
        // set legend position
        chart.legend().position("right");
        // set items layout
        chart.legend().itemsLayout("vertical");
        chart.sort("desc");
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: I'd suggest you watch tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VxOsCKMStuw for MVT setup and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iKB_4HWKMCc for MongoDB setup. To begin using Djangos MVT Archtecture. Follow the steps in the video for your scenario until your able to pass model data into the template. I can help once you've done so.

Comment: Uhmm, so what exactly is your question? How to retrieve data from mongodb? How to setup a django website? How to render template from django? How to pass data to your templates? You should check out official django tutorial to learn how to build using django.